# Gitlab ci with code quality: This GitLab CI configuration is invalid

Tags: maven, gitlab

My ci configuration isn't working with code quality stage:

```
image: maven:latest

stages:
  - code_quality
  - build

code_quality:
  image: docker:stable
  variables:
    DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2
  allow_failure: true
  services:
    - docker:stable-dind
  script:
    - export SP_VERSION=$(echo "$CI_SERVER_VERSION" | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\).*/\1-\2-stable/')
    - docker run
        --env SOURCE_CODE="$PWD"
        --volume "$PWD":/code
        --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        "registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/codequality:$SP_VERSION" /code
  artifacts:
    paths: [gl-code-quality-report.json]

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - mvn compile
```

Source example is here: https://gitlab.com/tyvain/mvn-ci-test/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

I cannot make it work with official gitlab example for code quality: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/examples/code_quality.html

The error is : " This GitLab CI configuration is invalid: code_quality job: stage parameter should be code_quality, build"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code_quality` stage is missing a `stage` parameter. Include that as below:

```
code_quality:
  stage: code_quality
  image: docker:stable
  ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Could be worthy to note that if you have a `.gitlab-cy.yml` file including 2 others, the `stages` part should be added to the main file.

Example :

> Main:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - analysis

include:
  - local: '/FRONTEND/.gitlab-ci.yml'
  - local: '/SERVER/.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

> Why?

Because if you put `stages` in each file, only one will be used (the last one for me) which may not have the same stages as the other. And so you'll have that type of error `job: stage parameter should be`.